# HTML tables: attribute for cells content editing?

Tags: html, html-table, editing

I would like to edit the content of a cell in an HTML table.

Is there an attribute for editing or I have to use some kind of script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself.. Just go in the wanted cell and put the `contenteditable` attribute like this:

```
<td contenteditable>Whatever</td>
```

Comment: I suggest you to check the w3 specs, as `td` may or may not support this property. It is available for the Div tag. For instance `<div contenteditable="true">abc</div>`

Comment: @NathanLee, in HTML5 CR, `contenteditable` is a general attribute defined for all elements; in earlier HTML specs, it does not exist at all.

Comment: True @JukkaK.Korpela I was not aware so told him to check and confirm that td may or may not support this property. Thnx for info.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to do it manually, then you have to define an `attribute` for the `td` and then by css, you have to apply the content that you want by declaring an `:after` or `:before` class.

For instance, Here is the [WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/9DTL4/)

**The HTML:**

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td title="abc">&nbsp;</td>
    <td title="def">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**The CSS:**

```
td[title=abc]:after{content:"red"}
td[title=def]:after{content:"blue"}
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: thx, but I was looking just for an html attribute allow me to set a cell content editable... I found it with a better google research :).. the attribute is contenteditable.

Comment: Oh. I thought you want to push contents inside the `td` without putting anything manually on page. - @LutherBlisset